# highcharts change exporting option dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I have chart option like below:

```
'chart' : {
    'defaultSeriesType' : 'bar',
    'renderTo' : QIS.WERM.CcySpotValuationContent.LINE_CHART_AREA_ID_
    },
'title' : {
    'text' : title
    },
'exporting':{
    'buttons': {
        'contextButton': {      
            'symbol':'url(/fxqis/public/images/excel.gif)',
            'onclick': function() {}
            }
        }
    }
```

but what I want is to use different exporting option dynamically. like following:

```
if(something){
    'exporting':{
        'buttons': {
            'contextButton': {      
                'symbol':'url(/fxqis/public/images/excel.gif)',
                'onclick': function() {}
                }
        }
    }
}
else{
    'exporting':{
        'enabled':false
        }
}
```

Can I add such if/else condition in the chart option? How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how you generate your javascript for the highcharts definition. We generate our javascript server side based on params/options/etc for the data session in question and then push the js to the page in a .NET register client script block code set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside JSON it is not possible, but you can use something like this:

```
var exportingOPT = {};

    if(condition)
       exportingOPT = {
         param: true
       }
    else
       exportingOPT = {
         param: false
       }
```

Then in chart configuration of Highcharts use:

```
chartOptions:exporingOPT
```

Answer (score 4):

Since version 5.0.0 you can simply do: 
(to update any options of the chart)

```
 chart.update({
        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    text: 'New Dynamic Text'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to manipulate within your default chart object (it's messy doesn't make for organized code). Figure out your default option and place it in your chart object. So, if it is to enable export options by default, then your code is like this:

```
'chart' : {
    'defaultSeriesType' : 'bar',
    'renderTo' : QIS.WERM.CcySpotValuationContent.LINE_CHART_AREA_ID_
},
'title' : {
    'text' : title
},
'exporting':{
   'buttons': {
    'contextButton': {      
        'symbol':'url(/fxqis/public/images/excel.gif)',
        'onclick': function() {}
        }
    }
}
```

Once that's done, refer to your chart object and manipulate the options OUTSIDE of the definition. You can use methods found in the API or quite literally manipulate it like you do any other object:

```
if(something){
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
chart.options.exporting.enabled = false;
}
```

You can use the API to set the export options like this: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.exportChart()

Answer (score 0):

You are really close to achieve what you need, simple change:

```
var ex;
if(something){
  ex = {
    'buttons': {
        'contextButton': {      
            'symbol':'url(/fxqis/public/images/excel.gif)',
            'onclick': function() {}
            }
    }
  }
}
else{
  ex = {
    'enabled':false
  }
}
```

Then when creating chart use:

```
 exporting: ex
```

And this should be enough.